# Can I expose a service with REST & SOAP via WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I want to architecture our software so that we can expose our API logic using WCF (SOAP and REST).

Im confused as to whether I have to use ASMX files if I want to do SOAP services, or whether .svc file can still do SOAP service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your svc file can provide the restful interface you are requesting. You just have to do a little configuring within your web configuration file, and decorate the svc class with the attributes to describe the behavior of our restful url.

here is a great article going over the steps:

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/779/simple-5-steps-to-expose-wcf-services-using-rest-style

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. You have to expose a SOAP end-point for your WCF service. This [MSDN post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412196.aspx) has an example.

Comment: +1 A very simple, yet complete article. I also like the lack of a configuration file, as well as the fact that the client isn't being generated by Microsoft's bloaty WCF service tool.